# static_cast<char> giving weird characters

Tags: c++, static-cast

I want to convert an integer to a character. I am new to C++ and used static type conversion but that is giving me weird characters.

**Actual Case:** I do not want the integer to be converted into a string because ultimately I have a vector of vector of characters `vector<vector<char>> vec` and I want to replace `vec[i][j]` with integer `i`. I tried doing `vec[i][j] = (character conversion of i as below)`:

```
int i = 1; //I want a character '1'
cout<<char(i); //It outputs ╔
cout<<(char)(i); //It outputs ╔
cout<<static_cast<char>(i); //It outputs ╔
```

I am curious to what might be going wrong in above type conversion? Also How can I change a character via its `[i][j]` index in a `vector<vector<char>>`.

Comment: Try `static_cast<char>(i+'0')`

Comment: `char(i)` means "The character at position `i` in the character encoding table" (probably ASCII).

Comment: Check out an [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: `I want a character '1'` Then write `'1'`.

Comment: @LDV You should explore ASCII. Try this: `for(int i=0; i<128; ++i) std::cout << i << " " << static_cast<char>(i) << "\n";` to get an idea.

Comment: What character do you want to convert it to?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "_int i = 1; //I want a character '1'_"

Comment: @TedLyngmo Haha time to go home I think

Comment: @eerorika I had a integer variable that I needed to convert to character i.e. `int a=1 //I need char(a) i.e. '1'`. Nevertheless I got the answer as pointed out in comments by @Ted Lyngmo